# React errors getting firestore document

Tags: reactjs, firebase

This is my code `Schedule.js`:

```
var uid;


firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        if (!user.emailVerified) {
            alert("An email was sent to you to verify your account. Please verify before logging in.");
            signOut();
        }
        uid = user.uid;
        if (window.location.pathname === "/signin" || window.location.pathname === "/signup") {
            window.location.href = "/";
        }
    } else {
        if (window.location.pathname !== '/signin' && window.location.pathname !== '/signup') {
            window.location.href = "/signin";
        }
    }
})

function Schedule() {
const classes = useStyles();
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

var day = days[now.getDay()];
var month = months[now.getMonth()];

getClassesFromFirestore();

function getClassesFromFirestore() {
    if (gotten === true) {
        return;
    }
    gotten = true;
    console.log(uid);
    firestore.db.collection('users').doc(uid).get().then((value) => {
        var data = value.data();
        console.log(data);
        if (data === undefined || Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
            createdClasses = [];
        }
        else {
            createdClasses = JSON.parse(data.classes);
        }
    })
    
}
```

I have documents named after each of my user's UID in "users" collection. It successfully gets the document data for the first time after code compile. However, if I refresh the page, `uid` becomes undefined and that causes `data` to be undefined as well. I tried `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` too but it's the same result. First time it works, after refresh `currentUser` is null.

Comment: As in "value" is undefined? Or something else is undefined?

Comment: `value` is a promise, `value.data()` is undefined.

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't really tell us anything, can you provide a full example please? Also make sure that uid exists all the time.

Comment: I updated the post. The UID exist all the time. If you need more code I can add it

Comment: Where does `uid` come from in this scenario? Are you sure `uid` is what you think it is In the case where data is undefined? Is it possible this is running before you've set uid? What does `updateClass()` do? What does this component return? You shouldn't be running naked data fetching inside your component's render.

Comment: the uid is from 

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if(user){
        uid = user.uid;
    })

Comment: `updateClass()` is unrelated to fetching data from firestore

Comment: It's still not clear--and I don't feel like asking again--where the `uid` you're referencing in this function is declared. I still suspect this function is running before uid is set. The firestore call is asynchronous (as is console.log) so by the time you log it inside your `then` it may have changed. What is the value of `uid` at the point where you make the firestore call?

Comment: I declared `uid` at the beginning of the js file, then right after that I set the `uid` with firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{uid = user.id}). Now that I think of it, the issue might be caused by `onAuthStateChanged` has a delay

Comment: Maybe onauthstatechange observer is not firing when you refresh (since you're already authenticated). For now try checking for currentUser to see if firebase remembers the login UID and try using that instead. Refer to here for details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: currentUser is null